# Itemize with alert

Tags: itemize

I am trying to produce a slide in beamer where each line comes out with alert. This is the code I am currently using:

```
\newenvironment{stepenumerate}{\begin{enumerate}[<+->]}{\end{enumerate}}
\newenvironment{stepitemize}{\begin{itemize}[<+->]}{\end{itemize}}
\newenvironment{stepenumeratewithalert}{\begin{enumerate}[<+-| alert@+>]}{\end{enumerate}}
\newenvironment{stepitemizewithalert}{\begin{itemize}[<+-| alert@+>]}{\end{itemize}}
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
\frametitle{The Title}
\framesubtitle {The title}
\begin{stepitemizewithalert}
\item This is the first line:
\end{stepitemizewithalert}
\begin{definition}<2->
This is the definition.
\end{definition}
\begin{stepitemizewithalert}
\item <3->This is the third line.
\end{stepitemizewithalert}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

As you may notice the first line is fine, but the definition and the third line do not come out with an alert. Could you please help me with this?

Thank you to all of you.

Best,

Dario

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that you are misusing beamer's `<3->` functionality. When you write

```
\item <3->This is the third line.
```

you are saying that this item should appear from side three onwards *without* an alert. In some sense the whole of using such an environment is to avoid having to manually insert all of the `<k->` commands.

The problem in your MWE is that the slide numbers in the `stepenumeratewithalert` environments are out of sync. This seems to always happen at the start of itemize environments, so I am not sure whether this is a bug of whether the beamer authors consider this is a feature.

In any case, you can manually "set" the side number at the start of the `stepenumeratewithalert` environment using the optional argument to the `\pause` command. In full detail, the following seems to do what you want:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\newenvironment{stepenumeratewithalert}{\begin{enumerate}[<+-| alert@+>]}{\end{enumerate}}
\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}[fragile]
  \begin{stepenumeratewithalert}
    \item This is the first line:
  \end{stepenumeratewithalert}

  \begin{definition}<2->
  This is the definition.
  \end{definition}

  \pause[3]% set current slide number equal to 3
  \begin{stepenumeratewithalert}
    \item This is the third line.
  \end{stepenumeratewithalert}
  \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Here is the output for the third slide:

[image]

For what it is worth, as much as possible I try to use `\pause`, rather than explicit `<k->` commands. For example, I would put `\pause` before the `definition` environment rather than hard-coding the the slide number with `<2->`. Sometimes, of course, this is unavoidable.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Andrew. It is almost what I need. Do you have any idea on how I could have the Definition (and its test) marked in red when it appears in the slide as the first and the third line?